# Is it true that any hamilton graph with "k" vertices has k/2 as the maximum independent set?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

A Hamilton graph  is a graph that has a Hamiltonian cycle ,which means a cycle exists in this graph in which you can visit every vertex of graph exactly  once .

My observation is  : - Say for a(any) Hamilton graph of 100 vertices , the value of its maximum independent set will be 50 .

Can somebody prove it or verify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is plainly false. The complete graph on $n>2$ vertices is Hamiltonian but has maximum independent set size of only $1$.

However, if a Hamiltonian graph on $2n$ vertices is *bipartite*, then it is true that its maximum independent set size is $n$ (take one bipartition).

Comment: maximum matching in a hamilton graph of "k" vertices is always (k+1)/2 , is this claim correct ??

Comment: @RiyaSingh Ask that as another question

Comment: here it is : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613511/maximum-matching-in-a-hamilton-graph-of-k-vertices-is-always-k1-2-is-this

Comment: I have one more question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612906/maximum-matching-in-general-graph .